# componentDidMount() is not setting values

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-redux, fetch

I am refactoring my code, I am trying to use all the lifecycle method available for me. I am trying to initialize the state of the component using componentDidMount(). Before, this I used this.props every time when trying to use properties from a parent component (and it worked until the code became to large), now I am trying to use this.state instead in order to rerender automatic after every change. Can someone tell me where I am wrong?

This is the code of App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import BasicLayout from './newtask2/BasicLayout2';
import fetch from 'cross-fetch';

class App extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       portletlocations: [],
       portlets: []
    }
  }

  loadPortletLocationsFromServer() {
    var self = this;
     try {
        fetch("http://localhost:8080/portletlocation/all", {
          headers : { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
          }
        }).then( (response) => {
          return response.json();
        }).then((json) => {
          console.log("Loaded from server", json);
          self.setState({portletlocations: json});
        })
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      } 
   }

  loadPortletsFromServer(){
    var self = this;
    try{
      fetch("http://localhost:8080/portlet/all", {

      }).then( (response) => {
        return response.json();
      }).then((json) => {
        console.log("Loaded from server", json);
        self.setState({portlets: json});
      })
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadPortletLocationsFromServer();
    this.loadPortletsFromServer();
  }

  render() {
    return ( <BasicLayout portletlocations={this.state.portletlocations} portlets = {this.state.portlets} /> );
  }
 }

 export default App;
```

And this is the part of the code of BasicLayout:

```
class BasicLayout extends React.PureComponent {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      open: false,
      portletlocations: [],
      portlets: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({
      portletlocations: this.props.portletlocations,
      portlets: this.props.portlets
    });
  }


  render() {
    if(this.state.portletlocations != undefined){
      console.log("portletlocations=", this.state.portletlocations); //here I get and empty array
```

Comment: `componentDidMount` will only be called once after the first `render`.

Comment: What should I use can you give any suggestions in code?

Comment: use `componentDidUpdate` instead of `componentDidMount`

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai well done I think this is the solution and it worked for now! :)

Comment: Read this article http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/ and check this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/0cN0tu?p=preview for clarity on the order of react life cycle methods.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this! :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be that those props are not available to the component yet, since they appear (from your provided code) to be load asynchronously.

If so, you should probably move the logic from `componentDidMount()` to `componentWillReceiveProps()`.

Something like this should work:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  if(nextProps.portletlocations || nextProps.portlets)
    this.setState({
      portletlocations: nextProps.portletlocations,
      portlets: nextProps.portlets
  });
}
```

Comment: Note: componentWillReceiveProps will be deprecated as of v17

Comment: Can you please @ruaanvds write your implementation of my code (part of it) in js bin?